# Skip a number in sequence of numbers generated using connect by

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Select Rownum From dual Connect By Rownum <= '4' ;
```

Am using this SQL to list numbers from 1 to 4.

i want to list 1 to 4 skipping 3. so that the result looks like

```
1
2
4
```

Kindly help

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: using oracle sql developer 4.1.0

Comment: Why do you want to skip 3? Is there a logic that you may need to extend to more than the first 4 numbers?

Comment: am using for ranking students. no two students can have same rank. so the rank numbers available in the dropdown should not have a particular rank which is already. jus a small part of a bigger puzzle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEVEL < 3 THEN LEVEL ELSE LEVEL + 1 END AS value
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL < 4;
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT LEVEL AS value
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4
)
WHERE  value <> 3;
```

or, since it is unclear how your sequence should progress beyond 4, you could do:

```
SELECT POWER( 2, LEVEL - 1 ) AS value
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3;
```